SQS Message from Lambda function never arrives at the queue
I have a project using Serverless Framework that has two functions - one an express API, which for some endpoints will communicate with the second function (reportGenerator), which is triggered by the arrival of an SQS message.  It works correctly locally (using serverless-offline with ElasticMQ running in docker and using the serverless-offline-sqs plugin).
When deployed, however, the message never shows up on the SQS dashboard, or (obviously) in the report generator.  There are no errors, the queue URL seems to match, but my dashboard shows zero messages arriving.
Here's the code to send the message:
    sendReportRequest: async function (reportId, companyId, userId, context = {}) {
        const body = {
            reportId: +reportId,
            companyId: +companyId,
            userId: +userId,
            context: context
        };
        let params = {
            QueueUrl: process.env.REPORT_REQUEST_QUEUE_URL,
            MessageAttributes: {
                "messageType": {
                    DataType: "String",
                    StringValue: "report"
                }
            },
            MessageBody: JSON.stringify(body)
        };
        let success = false;
        try {
            console.log(`sending SQS message: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
            await sqs.send(new SendMessageCommand(params));
            success = true;
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(`failed to send SQS message: ${ex.message}`);
        }
        return success;
    }

When that executes, this is the Cloudwatch log entry (account # in the URL replaced):
2024-12-02T02:27:20.930Z    f0b16796-ad97-45ad-a392-6eac6cc73da7    INFO    sending SQS message: 
{
    "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/staging-report-request",
    "MessageAttributes": {
        "messageType": {
            "DataType": "String",
            "StringValue": "report"
        }
    },
    "MessageBody": "{\"reportId\":1,\"companyId\":1,\"userId\":2,\"context\":{}}"
}


An almost straight copy/paste (again anonymizing the account #) from the SQS dashboard of the Queue URL is:
https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/staging-report-request.  You'll have to take my word for the fact that the actual account numbers in both places are the same :).
The mq was originally added a couple days ago, and the initial deployment using just a test message worked, so my working assumption is that I changed something somewhere, but without even an error message to go on, I don't know where.  The changes since that first test were to actually build out the report code, the only change to the serverless.yml being to add a timeout to the report function with a higher value than what's in the provider section.

"the message never shows up on the SQS dashboard"... are you in the correct region when looking? Also, is anything reading from the queue? Are the messages being processed before you can view them?

Good thoughts, but yes, yes, and no.  If I were in the wrong region, the queue itself would not show on the console, but it does, and I double-checked since I've definitely done that before.  Yes, the generator itself reads the queue, and logs everything to Cloudwatch, but since the monitor tab (what I called the dashboard) was showing zero "messages received", I didn't think it was relevant to the question.

Huh.  I spent many hours yesterday testing this deployed (after days of testing locally), with no messages sent.  8 hours later, and now messages are flowing.  Literally nothing changed.  Nothing in the dlq from prior tests, just a couple dozen messages that AWS-SDK said were sent, but never made it to the queue, and now things are working.  Perhaps just a weird outage?
